# How to achieve a progress circle that fills color with the increase in percentage in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, timer, progress-bar

My requirement is to have a progress circle with countdown timer inside the circle. The timer keeps ticking down, meanwhile the circle keeps filling up. Once the timer gets to 0, the circle is full.

I am not able to find any plugin that suits my needs. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

okay so you can use

```
npm install react-circular-progressbar
```

install this package and use it as

```
import {CircularProgressbar} from 'react-circular-progressbar';

<CircularProgressbar percentage={60} />
```

you can maintain the progress in state or whatever way you like and in percentage you can set that state.

Comment: But, I want to fill the complete circle, like a pie getting eaten, but in reverse. Also, how to convert remaining seconds into percentage?

Comment: You might wanna update your import statement:
import { CircularProgressbar } from "react-circular-progressbar";